# Tried everything... ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1007)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, openssl

I've tried so many combinations to get this working with zero success. Here is my code. Here is the latest version of my code. Please help.

Wesbite: https://www.legislation.gov.au/

I keep getting ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1007)

I run this
`openssl s_client -connect www.legislation.gov.au:443 -tls1_2` to even check the settings.

Can anyone manage to do a basic request on this website without getting that exception? It's doing my head in...

```
import httpx
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import asyncio
import ssl
import socket
import sys

async def fetch_data():
    sitemap_url = "https://www.legislation.gov.au/Browse/ByTitle/LegislativeInstruments/InForce/0/0/All/"
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36"
    }
    
    ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    ssl_context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1  # Only TLS 1.1 allowed

    # Wrap the socket with an SSL context
    socketHandler = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socketWraped = ssl_context.wrap_socket(socketHandler, server_hostname='www.legislation.gov.au')
    socketWraped.connect(('www.legislation.gov.au', 443))

    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.get(sitemap_url, headers=headers, timeout=10, socket=socketWraped)
        response.raise_for_status()
        html_content = response.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
    
    # Your parsing and processing code here
    print("Successfully fetched and parsed data.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(fetch_data())
```

Comment: Why not directly use an http client that can do all of that for you? You don't need to make a whole socket and ssl connection yourself